# `renderPrint` vertical bar `¦` and/or degree `°` characters

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to find out if certain "rare" characters can be correctly printed in R `shiny` via `renderPrint` - INFO: I know that `renderText` will print these characters but that is not the question, since I am trying to print a (package) `data.tree` structure where nodes et al are depicted by those `¦` and `°` characters, sadly not `|` (pipe) because that 'interestingly' renders correctly, and that printed `data.tree` will only offer itself to `renderPrint` because of it being a list structure (under the hood when printed) so not available to `cat` and therefore also not "easily" available to `renderText`.

Here's a reprex of what I'm talking about

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
    h5("not printing as desired"), 
    verbatimTextOutput("verbatimOut"),
    br(),
    h5("printing as desired"),
    textOutput("textOut")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$verbatimOut <- renderPrint({
        print("|  ¦ °")
    })
    output$textOut <- renderText({
        print("|  ¦ °")
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

output:
[image]

Any ideas appreciated ... thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found out what the reason for the above output was ... as is so often the case `locale` "hell" on Windows

Initial `sessionInfo()` output:

```
R version 4.1.3 (2022-03-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19044)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] shiny_1.7.4 clipr_0.8.0 fcuk_0.1.21

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.9        jquerylib_0.1.4   bslib_0.4.2       compiler_4.1.3    pillar_1.8.1      later_1.3.0      
 [7] urlchecker_1.0.1  prettyunits_1.1.1 profvis_0.3.7     remotes_2.4.2     tools_4.1.3       digest_0.6.31    
[13] pkgbuild_1.4.0    pkgload_1.3.2     jsonlite_1.8.4    tibble_3.1.8      memoise_2.0.1     lifecycle_1.0.3  
[19] pkgconfig_2.0.3   rlang_1.0.6       reprex_2.0.2      cli_3.5.0         rstudioapi_0.14   parallel_4.1.3   
[25] fastmap_1.1.0     withr_2.5.0       stringr_1.5.0     sass_0.4.4        fs_1.5.2          vctrs_0.5.1      
[31] htmlwidgets_1.6.0 devtools_2.4.5    prompt_1.0.1      glue_1.6.2        R6_2.5.1          processx_3.8.0   
[37] fansi_1.0.3       sessioninfo_1.2.2 callr_3.7.3       purrr_1.0.0       magrittr_2.0.3    ps_1.7.2         
[43] promises_1.2.0.1  ellipsis_0.3.2    htmltools_0.5.4   usethis_2.1.6     stringdist_0.9.10 memuse_4.2-2     
[49] mime_0.12         xtable_1.8-4      httpuv_1.6.7      utf8_1.2.2        stringi_1.7.8     miniUI_0.1.1.1   
[55] cachem_1.0.6      crayon_1.5.2
```

NOTICE THE `locale` being `C`

When I set the `locale` to eg `English_US` it would, since I was on Windows here, change it to something like

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "English_US")
[1] "LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252;LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252;LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=English_United States.1252"
```

and after that the output would be the desired/expected one (short additional remark: "LC_CTYPE" is the locale setting responsible for altering those printed characters in my case):
[image]